# Which is quicker EXISTS outside NONEMPTY or EXISTS inside NONEMPTY

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to test which is more efficient:

- `EXISTS` outside `NONEMPTY`
- `EXISTS` inside `NONEMPTY`

A couple of trivial examples are as follows. Both run in 1 second so how do I analyse which is best?

`EXISTS` outside `NONEMPTY`

```
SELECT 
    {}
    ON 0, 
    EXISTS(
        NONEMPTY( 
            [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS 
            , {([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20060701], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])} 
        ),
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany] 
    )
    ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

`EXISTS` inside `NONEMPTY`

```
SELECT 
    {}
    ON 0, 
    NONEMPTY( 
        EXISTS(
            [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS 
            , [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]  
        ),
        {([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20060701], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])}
    )
    ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test like this, [MDX Studio](http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio) is a useful tool. This was developed by one of the core developers of the Analysis Services engine, Mosha Pasumansky. There is no detailed documentation apart from some blog posts from Mosha, and there used to be a forum some years ago which may have disappeared, as Mosha moved on away from Analysis Services.

To check the performance of a query, enter it on a query tab, and then hit the "Profile" button. This will clear the Analysis Services cache, and execute the calculation script of the cube, and then two times your query. The first time, the query is running on a cold cache, and the second time on a warm cache, as the exact same query was executed just immediately before.

Comment: @FrankPI - I have this tool. Ashamed to say all I use it for is formatting! Which section of the tool covers efficiency. p.s. I noticed yesterday that MS have deleted the images used by Mosha's blog ...http://superuser.com/questions/784254/anyway-to-get-these-png-files-to-render

Comment: @FrankPI - I'll try this - if it was a production cube would I need to be wary of clearing the cache or is it not so important in AS ?

Comment: @whytheq Clearing the cache may make some queries slower, maybe dramatically slower. You start with a clean cache after each cube update, however. So if users do not complain after structural cube changes or after a cube processing, it should not be too annoying. Another issue, however, would be that concurrent queries on the same cube could skew your performance measurements.

Comment: @FrankPI - if on Prod cube I'll get in early and use this Profile as our cubes are updated once per day before everyone arrives. Great info - thank you.